# Why does np.ndarray.__deepcopy__ require a superfluous argument?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy, deep-copy

The duplicate will answer `what`, but will not adequately answer `why` or why it is not mentioned in the docs even though it is required. Read on for more...

---

There are two ways of making a deep copy of a numpy array. One way is using `copy.deepcopy` from the `copy` module. The other way is to call `array.__deepcopy__` directly.

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.__deepcopy__.html):

> ```
> ndarray.__deepcopy__() → Deep copy of array.
> ```
>
> Used if `copy.deepcopy` is called on an array.

The docs hint that the right way to call this function is without any argument. However....

```
In [47]: x
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])

In [48]: x.__deepcopy__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-00c3b8eda618> in <module>()
----> 1 x.__deepcopy__()

TypeError: __deepcopy__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

A `TypeError` is returned! But...

```
In [51]: x.__deepcopy__(None)
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

And even...

```
In [52]: x.__deepcopy__([12345, 'blah blah'])
Out[52]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

It appears this function requires an argument but that argument supposedly has no bearing on the returned copy.

This argument is not mentioned in the documentation. Is it a doc bug? Why is it even passed in if it is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python requires the `__deepcopy__()` method to take one argument `memo` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)):

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; **it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary**. If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

Its purpose is to

> keeping a “memo” dictionary of objects already copied during the current copying pass

This prevents recursive loops during copying if objects contain reference cycles.

I guess numpy does not need to use that argument because an array normally does not hold recursive references to other Python objects, so it is simply ignored.

Comment: Ah, nice. So you would consider this lack of mention a documentation bug?

Comment: No, since I don't think you are supposed to call `__whatever__` functions directly during normal use.